# comparison between two floating value in python

Tags: python, comparison

I am new to python programming.

I have written some simple python code as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def reducer():
    bigSale = 0
    oldKey = None
    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        if len(data) != 2:
                continue
        thisKey, thisSale = data
        print oldKey,bigSale,thisKey,thisSale
        if not oldKey:
                oldKey = thisKey
                bigSale = thisSale
                print "This is first if and value of oldKey and bigSale are ",oldKey," ",bigSale
        elif oldKey and oldKey != thisKey:
                print "{0}\t{1}".format(oldKey, bigSale)
                oldKey = thisKey
                bigSale = 0
        elif(oldKey and oldKey == thisKey and thisSale > bigSale):
                print "Observe the expression : ", thisSale, " > " , bigSale , " has a boolean value of ", thisSale > bigSale
                print "This is the second elif construct and value of bigSale before assignment is ",bigSale
                bigSale = thisSale
                print "This is the second elif construct and value of bigSale after assignment is ",bigSale
                print "Now the new value of oldKey and bigSale are: ",oldKey," ",bigSale
    if oldKey != None and thisSale > bigSale:
        print "{0}\t{1}".format(oldKey, bigSale)

def main():
        reducer()

main()
```

I am passing below data as input:

```
Anchorage       22.36
Anchorage       298.86
Anchorage       6.38
Aurora  117.81
Austin  327.75
Austin  379.6
Austin  469.63
Boston  418.94
Buffalo 483.82
Chandler        344.09
Chandler        414.08
Chicago 31.08
Corpus Christi  25.38
Fort Wayne      370.55
Fort Worth      153.57
Fort Worth      213.88
Fremont 222.61
Fresno  466.64
Greensboro      290.82
Honolulu        345.18
Houston 309.16
Indianapolis    135.96
Las Vegas       53.26
Las Vegas       93.39
Lincoln 136.9
Madison 16.78
Minneapolis     182.05
Newark  39.75
New York        296.8
Norfolk 189.01
Omaha   235.63
Omaha   255.68
Philadelphia    351.31
Pittsburgh      475.26
Pittsburgh      493.51
Portland        108.69
Reno    80.46
Reno    88.25
Riverside       15.41
Riverside       252.88
San Bernardino  170.2
San Diego       66.08
San Francisco   260.65
San Jose        214.05
San Jose        215.82
Spokane 287.65
Spokane 3.85
Stockton        247.18
Tulsa   205.06
Virginia Beach  376.11
```

When I see the output with the help of debugging statements, I found that float comparison is not happening as expected
Please find below snippet of the output i got when i run the code on sample data:

None 0 Anchorage 22.36
This is first if and value of oldKey and bigSale are  Anchorage   22.36
Anchorage 22.36 Anchorage 298.86

Observe the expression :  `298.86  >  22.36`  has a Boolean value of  True
This is the second `elif` construct and value of bigSale before assignment is  22.36

This is the second `elif` construct and value of bigSale after assignment is  298.86

Now the new value of oldKey and bigSale are:  Anchorage   298.86
Anchorage 298.86 Anchorage 6.38

**Observe the expression :  6.38  >  298.86  has a Boolean value of  True**

This is the second elif construct and value of bigSale before assignment is  298.86

This is the second elif construct and value of bigSale after assignment is  6.38
Now the new value of oldKey and bigSale are:  Anchorage   6.38

Could anyone please help me where i am doing it wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the bad indentation of sample output provided:
Please see below sample input with proper indentation:
Anchorage       22.36
Anchorage       298.86
Anchorage       6.38
Aurora  117.81
Austin  327.75
Austin  379.6
Austin  469.63
Boston  418.94
Buffalo 483.82
Chandler        344.09
Chandler        414.08
Chicago 31.08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem you are facing is that you compare `string` to `string` instead of `float` to `float`

When comparing strings indeed `6.38 > 298.86` has a Boolean value of `True` since 6 is greater than 2.

In order to compare `float` to `float`, you'll need to cast the string to a float, using `float(str)`

e.g.

```
>>> float('1.99') 
1.99
```

For example, you can change your code (in all cases when you compare float values) in the following style:

```
    elif(oldKey and oldKey == thisKey and float(thisSale) > float(bigSale)):
```

Also, you can assign the values to the variables as float, instead of as string. Again using casting to float using `float(str_number)` 
More info about python data type conversion:

- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float
- http://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/data_types_conversion.html